# SSIS Npgsql Connection Authentication method not supported

Tags: sql-server, ssis, npgsql

After upgrading the source database, the previously working package does not execute and reports the following error. Does anyone know what and where to update in the SSIS server? I hope that it will not be necessary to upgrade the SQL server version?

> Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection X with the following error message: "Authentication method not supported (Received: 10)"
>
> ADO.NET:Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql,
> Version=3.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7

MS SQL Server/SSIS Version: 14.0.2037.2

EDIT 2023.12.05
The most important question is probably whether ado.net uses the latest version of Npgsql installed on the server? Or does it have a copy hidden somewhere and cannot be updated?

I solved this case, or rather circumvented it, by installing another driver and creating a new connection based on new driver. Then, using notepad and ctrl+h, I replaced the occurrences of the old connection in the dtsx files.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details than that if you hope for a meaningful answer. What is the "source database", what was its version before the upgrade, what it is now, what is the version of the driver you use to connect to it, what does the connection string look like, stuff like that.